# What's the entropy of the output for Tiger Encryption?

Tags: hash, entropy

I'm tasked to apply tiger encryption to my string(key). Does anyone have any idea how to find the entropy of the hex output by tiger encryption?

Comment: Tiger is a cryptographic message digest, it is not encryption. The resultant digest will have the same entropy as the input key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tiger is a 192-bit cryptographic message digest (hash function).

A design goal of an ideal hash function is to distribute the input entropy evenly over the message digest.

If an input string of 40 bytes with 28 bytes (224 bits) of entropy is hashed by Tiger, the resultant 192-bit string will have at most 192 bits, since the output cannot have more entropy than its size.

If the input string has 28 bits of entropy, the resultant 192-bit string will have at most 28 bits, since the output cannot have more entropy than the input.

A hash function is not encryption.